# In Flutter - How do I push user to a "Thank-you" page in the app after returning from PayPal completed transaction page in web browser

Tags: flutter, paypal

My flutter app requires payments to be made via PayPal in a web browser outside the app. Once the payment is completed the user will be returned to the app and a thank you page should be pushed.

I'm using _launchURL to initiate the web browser from within the app and the following example PayPal url to define the payment.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=email@domain.com&currency_code=USD&amount=123.99&return=http://example.com&item_name=Document+Studio

Using SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler I should be able to test when the app returns from the web browser (AppLifecycleState.resumed). But how do I capture the return URL (http://example.com) or some other value from the web browser to confirm that it has come from the transaction complete page and should be pushed to the apps thank-you page?

Is there a way to pass a value from the browser back to the app?

My other thought was to use Uni_links to "Deep Link" the thank you page within the app and have that as the return url parameter in the PayPal url?

I'm a bit lost with the solution and am only new to flutter, so any advice/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using this _launchURL.  To do what you desire create a ThankYou class and call it in the following manner.  You might want to check resultingValue prior to calling your ThankYou screen.  I haven't used the url functionality enough to know what it returns, if anything.  It might be null, an int of some sort, such as 404 url not found, perhaps a String?

```
import 'ThankYou.dart';

_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.io';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url).then((resultingValue){
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ThankYou()));

    });

  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: I checked the url_launcher library and it says the launch() function returns a bool.  So you would test with:

if ( resultingValue == true ) {  Navigator...... }

https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/launch.html

Comment: That solves the problem of sending the user to the ThankYou page when they return to the app from the browser. However, it will always return the user to the thankyou page even if the user returns before completing the PayPal payment. Is there a way to capture/set the returning url so we know where the user returned from?

The PayPal url above is supposed to return "http://example.com" when successful. Is there a way to capture this or another way to deal with this problem?Thanks for the help E.Bradford

Comment: I'm not familiar with PayPal's API but I would assume it provides a secure technique of posting transaction data such as API key, passwords, $ amounts, etc.

Thus, investigate the PayPal programming API and look specifically for how to post a transaction to Paypal and then what data would it return.  Conceptually, the data it returns would be captured in the resultingValue variable.

I am thinking you are actually using the wrong technique to call out to PayPal _launchUrl is pretty rudimentary.  I would suggest using the Flutter library Dio instead.  Far better suited to this task.

Comment: You can find Dio here:  https://github.com/flutterchina/dio

Once you feel comfortable with Dio then move on to the PayPal API interface.